# Two streams of writing to file

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, filestream

When the writing starts from one file to the resulting file, the entry passes, and from the second file to this result file is blocked. So in two streams record can not be available in the same time. Error: a process can not access a file because this file is being used by another process. How I can resolve this problem. I tried diffrent ways. For example, If you write directly not to a file from two streams, but add string to some array, and then at the end go through the array and write everything to a file. It must be without synschronized.

```
class Program
{
    public static void WriteOneThread()
    {
        List<char> listOfChars = new List<char>();
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\test\task.txt");
        FileStream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(str);

        char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            listOfChars.Add(arr[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));
        FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(@"C:\test\Result.txt");
        try
        {
            foreach (var value in listOfChars)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = file2.CreateText();
                writer.WriteLine(value);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }        
}
    public static void WriteSecondThread()
    {
        List<char> listOfChars = new List<char>();
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\test\pretask.txt");
        FileStream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(str);

        char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            listOfChars.Add(arr[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));
        FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(@"C:\test\Result.txt");
        try
        {
            foreach (var value in listOfChars)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = file2.CreateText();
                writer.WriteLine(value);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }      
}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread threadOne = new Thread(WriteOneThread);
        Thread threadSecond = new Thread(WriteSecondThread);

        threadOne.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        threadSecond.Start();

        threadOne.Join();
        threadSecond.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Запись в файл осуществлена");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the File.Open which takes a fileShare parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx
FileShare: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a design problem. You have made a race condition intentionally.